# switch between production and test API withing the App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I am building an app and would like to know what's the best way to implement a way to switch between production and test end points within the app itself on the fly.
and if that's possible how would that affect the cache

Thank you

Comment: My suggestion, create a default `hostUrl` in config and expose it using a getter. Then create an admin screen and set `overrideHostUrl` which would be blank by default. In getter do `return overrideHostUrl || hostUrl`. Also make sure to make privileges for admin screen as it can break your prod. Also, that will affect caching a lot. But I dont have much knowledge on that so will leave that to someone more experienced

Comment: do you mean I cat create a set function in config to change the url? how am I going to change it?

Comment: I'll try to make a small snippet and answer it tomorrow